# ReactJs - Passing function as props to setState - Which component's state will be updated?

Tags: reactjs

Let's say you have a Parent component which defines a method:

```
    class Parent extends Component {
     handleX() {
       this.setState({ x: true });
     }
   }
```

If I pass this function as props to Child and call it on for example a button click, which state will be updated - Child or Parent? What is the correct way to use this?

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither. If you want to update the parent state, you need to either hard-bind it or change it to a public class field (`handleX = () => { this.setState({ x: true })}`). But you will not be able to update the child state because of how `this` works.

```
handleX = () => {
  this.setState({ x: true })
}
```

or

```
<Child handleX={handleX.bind(this)} />
```

or

```
<Child handleX={() => handleX()} />
```

If you want to learn more about how `this` works in JS, refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work), or google it, there are tons of articles out there. Personally, I found Kyle's [You don't know JS - This and object prototypes](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes) more than helpful

Comment: @lonut - Thanks for your answer! I am having a difficult time understanding this bining of this in javascript - Do you have any good places for a thorough explanation?

Comment: @Alex5207, I corrected the answer and added some links for you

Comment: Thanks a lot! Much appreciated